# Complex value of z for real and imaginary part and modulus

Tags: complex-analysis

how do we go about if the function is $g(z) = e^{-2z}$ ?

what values of $z$ makes $g(z)$ real, imaginary, or modulus <1?

$g(z) = e^{-2(x+iy)} $ = $e^{-2x-i2y} $

=  $e^{-2x}e^{i(-2y)} $ =$e^{-2x}  [\cos(-2x)+i\sin(-2x)]$

Hence, real if $\cos(-2x)=0$ ?

What about $z$ = ? =

Comment: What do you mean by "$z=?=$"

Comment: the question explicitly asks for values of $z$ where $g$ is real, imaginary, or modulus <1

Comment: Ok, then you should make it clearer in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g(z)=e^{-2x}(\cos 2y-i\sin 2y)$. So $g(z)$ is real iff $e^{-2x}\sin 2y=0\implies y=\frac{n\pi}{2},n\in \mathbb{Z}$ which is a set of horizontal lines in complex plane. Similarly $g(z)$ is imaginary if $y=\frac{2n+1}{4}\pi,\ n\in \mathbb{Z}$. $|g(z)|=e^{-2x}\le 1\ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^+\cup\{0\}$, i.e. $g(z)$ is inside the unit circle in complex plane $\forall z\in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Hi Samrat thanks for the help. however, how do we explicitly find the values of $z$ and not only $y$?

Comment: For the case, say $y=\frac{n\pi}{2}$, the $x$ value can be anything, i.e. $x\in \mathbb{R}$, so $z$ can be any one of the points on the line $y=\frac{n\pi}{2}$

Comment: isnt $g(z) = e^{-2x}(cos(-2y)-isin(-2y)$) ?

Comment: @rebc $e^{-i2y}=\cos (-2y)+i\sin(-2y)=\cos(2y)-i\sin(2y)$